# How do I Replace the Name of A Group on A SharePoint 2010 Content Query Webpart

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, content-query-web-part, content-query-rollup

I have a Content Query Webpart (Not a dataview) which displays a list of articles that were written that day on the home page. I need to be able to group the items by Category, however by default the Categories are Alphabetized A through B instead of by priority (something I can change/edit/update).

I've tried a few different combinations. I am attaching a List of Fields, and I will put the code here.

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

**Columns**
Title - Single line of text
Creation Date Override - Date and Time
News Source - Single line of text
Original Author - Single line of text
Original Publishing Date - Date and Time
Article Text - Multiple lines of text
Month - Calculated (calculation based on other columns)
Month ID - Calculated (calculation based on other columns)
ISODate - Calculated (calculation based on other columns)
Category - Choice
Group Order - Lookup
Group Order:HomePage Order - Lookup
Created By - Person or Group
Modified By - Person or Group

(I know group order is a terrible name, but I got tired of remaking the list and Category was temporarily being used)

```
    Header.xsl
    <xsl:stylesheet
version="1.0"
exclude-result-prefixes="x d xsl msxsl cmswrt"
xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp"
xmlns:cmswrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v3/Publishing/runtime"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<xsl:template name="DefaultHeader" match="*" mode="header">
<div class="groupheader item medium">
  <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetGroupName">
    <xsl:with-param name="GroupName" select="@*[name()=$Group]"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="GroupType" select="$GroupType"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="LargeText" match="*[@GroupStyle='LargeText']" mode="header">
<div class="groupheader item large">
  <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetGroupName">
      <xsl:with-param name="GroupName" select="@Category"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="GroupType" select="$GroupType"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="SmallText" match="*[@GroupStyle='SmallText']" mode="header">
<div class="groupheader item small">
  <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetGroupName">
      <xsl:with-param name="GroupName" select="@*[name()=$Group]"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="GroupType" select="$GroupType"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="Band" match="*[@GroupStyle='Band']" mode="header">
<div class="groupheader item band">
  <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetGroupName">
      <xsl:with-param name="GroupName" select="@*[name()=$Group]"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="GroupType" select="$GroupType"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="Centered" match="*[@GroupStyle='Centered']" mode="header">
<div class="groupheader item centered">
  <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetGroupName">
      <xsl:with-param name="GroupName" select="@*[name()=$Group]"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="GroupType" select="$GroupType"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="Separator" match="*[@GroupStyle='Separator']" mode="header">
<div class="separator">
</div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="Whitespace" match="*[@GroupStyle='Whitespace']" mode="header">
<div class="whitespace">
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</div>
</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="AddCategory" match="*[@GroupStyle='AddCategory']" mode="header">
      <div class="whitespace">
          <xsl:value-of select="@Category" />
      </div>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


 Main.xml
     <xsl:stylesheet
version="1.0"
exclude-result-prefixes="x xsl cmswrt cbq" 
xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:cmswrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3/Publishing/runtime"
xmlns:cbq="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:ContentByQueryWebPart" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" media-type="text/html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="cbq_isgrouping" />
<xsl:param name="cbq_columnwidth" />
<xsl:param name="Group" />
<xsl:param name="GroupType" />
<xsl:param name="cbq_iseditmode" />
<xsl:param name="cbq_viewemptytext" />
<xsl:param name="cbq_errortext" />
<xsl:param name="SiteId" />
<xsl:param name="WebUrl" />
<xsl:param name="PageId" />
<xsl:param name="WebPartId" />
<xsl:param name="FeedPageUrl" />
<xsl:param name="FeedEnabled" />
<xsl:param name="SiteUrl" />
<xsl:param name="BlankTitle" />
<xsl:param name="BlankGroup" />
<xsl:param name="UseCopyUtil" />
<xsl:param name="DataColumnTypes" />
<xsl:param name="ClientId" />
<xsl:param name="Source" />
<xsl:param name="RootSiteRef" />
<xsl:param name="CBQPageUrl" />
<xsl:param name="CBQPageUrlQueryStringForFilters" />
<xsl:variable name="BeginList" select="string('&lt;ul class=&quot;dfwp-list&quot;&gt;')" />
<xsl:variable name="EndList" select="string('&lt;/ul&gt;')" />
<xsl:variable name="BeginListItem" select="string('&lt;li class=&quot;dfwp-item&quot;&gt;')" />
<xsl:variable name="EndListItem" select="string('&lt;/li&gt;')" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate">
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row" />
    <xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)" />
    <xsl:variable name="IsEmpty" select="$RowCount = 0" />
        <div id="{concat('cbqwp', $ClientId)}" class="cbq-layout-main">
             <xsl:if test="$cbq_iseditmode = 'True' and string-length($cbq_errortext) != 0">
                <div class="wp-content description">
                    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$cbq_errortext" />
                </div>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="$IsEmpty">
                       <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.Empty" >
                           <xsl:with-param name="EditMode" select="$cbq_iseditmode" />
                       </xsl:call-template>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                       <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.Body">
                           <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows" />
                           <xsl:with-param name="FirstRow" select="1" />
                           <xsl:with-param name="LastRow" select="$RowCount" />
                      </xsl:call-template>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
        </div>
        <xsl:if test="$FeedEnabled = 'True' and $PageId != ''">
            <div class="cqfeed">
                <xsl:variable name="FeedUrl1" select="concat($SiteUrl,$FeedPageUrl,'xsl=1&amp;web=',$WebUrl,'&amp;page=',$PageId,'&amp;wp=',$WebPartId,'&amp;pageurl=',$CBQPageUrl,$CBQPageUrlQueryStringForFilters)" />
                <a href="{cmswrt:RegisterFeedUrl( $FeedUrl1, 'application/rss+xml')}"><img src="\_layouts\images\rss.gif" border="0" alt="{cmswrt:GetPublishingResource('CbqRssAlt')}"/></a>
            </div>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.Empty">
    <xsl:param name="EditMode" />
        <xsl:if test="$EditMode = 'True' and string-length($cbq_errortext) = 0">
            <div class="wp-content description">
                <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$cbq_viewemptytext" />
            </div>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.Body">
  <xsl:param name="Rows" />
  <xsl:param name="FirstRow" />
  <xsl:param name="LastRow" />
  <xsl:variable name="BeginColumn1" select="string('&lt;ul class=&quot;dfwp-column dfwp-list&quot; style=&quot;width:')" />
  <xsl:variable name="BeginColumn2" select="string('%&quot; &gt;')" />
  <xsl:variable name="BeginColumn" select="concat($BeginColumn1, $cbq_columnwidth, $BeginColumn2)" />
  <xsl:variable name="EndColumn" select="string('&lt;/ul&gt;')" />
  <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
        <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
        <xsl:if test="($CurPosition &gt;= $FirstRow and $CurPosition &lt;= $LastRow)">
            <xsl:variable name="StartNewGroup" select="@__begingroup = 'True'" />
            <xsl:variable name="StartNewColumn" select="@__begincolumn = 'True'" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$cbq_isgrouping != 'True'">
                    <xsl:if test="$CurPosition = $FirstRow">
                        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$BeginColumn" />
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$StartNewGroup and $StartNewColumn">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$CurPosition = $FirstRow">
                            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$BeginColumn" />
                            <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallHeaderTemplate"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallFooterTemplate"/>
                            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="concat($EndColumn, $BeginColumn)" />
                            <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallHeaderTemplate"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$StartNewGroup">
                    <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallFooterTemplate"/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallHeaderTemplate"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$StartNewColumn">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$CurPosition = $FirstRow">
                            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$BeginColumn" />
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="concat($EndColumn, $BeginColumn)" />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallItemTemplate">
                <xsl:with-param name="CurPosition" select="$CurPosition" />
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:if test="$CurPosition = $LastRow">
              <xsl:if test="$cbq_isgrouping = 'True'">
                <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallFooterTemplate"/>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$EndColumn" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.CallHeaderTemplate">
  <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$BeginListItem" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="header">
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$BeginList" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.CallItemTemplate">
<xsl:param name="CurPosition" />
  <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$BeginListItem" />
  <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@Style='NewsRollUpItem'">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="itemstyle">
                 <xsl:with-param name="EditMode" select="$cbq_iseditmode" />
              </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="@Style='NewsBigItem'">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="itemstyle">
                 <xsl:with-param name="CurPos" select="$CurPosition" />
              </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="@Style='NewsCategoryItem'">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="itemstyle">
                 <xsl:with-param name="CurPos" select="$CurPosition" />
              </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="itemstyle">
              </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$EndListItem" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.CallFooterTemplate">
  <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$EndList" />
  <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$EndListItem" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
    <xsl:param name="UrlColumnName"/>
    <xsl:if test="$UseCopyUtil = 'True'">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($RootSiteRef,'/_layouts/CopyUtil.aspx?Use=id&amp;Action=dispform&amp;ItemId=',@ID,'&amp;ListId=',@ListId,'&amp;WebId=',@WebId,'&amp;SiteId=',$SiteId,'&amp;Source=',$Source)"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$UseCopyUtil != 'True'">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeStaticUrl">
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="$UrlColumnName"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">
    <xsl:param name="Title"/>
    <xsl:param name="UrlColumnName"/>
    <xsl:param name="UseFileName" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="string-length($Title) != 0 and $UseFileName = 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="$Title" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$UseCopyUtil = 'True' and $UseFileName = 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="$BlankTitle" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:variable name="FileNameWithExtension">
                <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetPageNameFromUrl">
                    <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="$UrlColumnName" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$UseFileName = 1">
                  <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetFileNameWithoutExtension">
                    <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$FileNameWithExtension" />
                  </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$FileNameWithExtension" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.FormatColumnIntoUrl">
    <xsl:param name="UrlColumnName"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Value" select="@*[name()=$UrlColumnName]"/>
    <xsl:if test="contains($DataColumnTypes,concat(';',$UrlColumnName,',URL;'))">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.FormatValueIntoUrl">
            <xsl:with-param name="Value" select="$Value"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not(contains($DataColumnTypes,concat(';',$UrlColumnName,',URL;')))">
        <xsl:value-of select="$Value"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.FormatValueIntoUrl">
    <xsl:param name="Value"/>
    <xsl:if test="not(contains($Value,', '))">
        <xsl:value-of select="$Value"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains($Value,', ')">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.Replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="Value" select="substring-before($Value,', ')"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="Search" select="',,'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="Replace" select="','"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.Replace">
    <xsl:param name="Value"/>
    <xsl:param name="Search"/>
    <xsl:param name="Replace"/>
    <xsl:if test="contains($Value,$Search)">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($Value,$Search),$Replace)"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.Replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="Value" select="substring-after($Value,$Search)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="Search" select="$Search"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="Replace" select="$Replace"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not(contains($Value,$Search))">
        <xsl:value-of select="$Value"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeStaticUrl">
    <xsl:param name="UrlColumnName"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Url">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.FormatColumnIntoUrl">
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="$UrlColumnName"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="cmswrt:EnsureIsAllowedProtocol($Url)"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.GetColumnDataForUnescapedOutput">
    <xsl:param name="Name"/>
    <xsl:param name="MustBeOfType"/>
    <xsl:if test="contains($DataColumnTypes,concat(';',$Name,',',$MustBeOfType,';'))">
        <xsl:value-of select="@*[name()=$Name]"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.GetPageNameFromUrl">
    <xsl:param name="UrlColumnName"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Url">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.FormatColumnIntoUrl">
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="$UrlColumnName"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetPageNameFromUrlRecursive">
        <xsl:with-param name="Url" select="$Url"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.GetPageNameFromUrlRecursive">
    <xsl:param name="Url"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($Url,'/') and substring($Url,string-length($Url)) != '/'">
            <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetPageNameFromUrlRecursive">
                <xsl:with-param name="Url" select="substring-after($Url,'/')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Url"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.GetGroupName">
    <xsl:param name="GroupName"/>
    <xsl:param name="GroupType"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length(normalize-space($GroupName)) = 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="$BlankGroup"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$GroupType='URL'">
                    <xsl:variable name="Url">
                        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.FormatValueIntoUrl">
                            <xsl:with-param name="Value" select="$GroupName"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetPageNameFromUrlRecursive">
                        <xsl:with-param name="Url" select="$Url"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:variable name="GroupOrder" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@Groupx0020Order" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.CallPresenceStatusIconTemplate">
    <xsl:if test="string-length(@SipAddress) != 0">
      <span class="presence-status-icon"><img src="/_layouts/images/imnhdr.gif" onload="IMNRC('{@SipAddress}')" ShowOfflinePawn="1" alt="" id="{concat('MWP_pawn_',$ClientId,'_',@ID,'type=sip')}"/></span>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.GetFileNameWithoutExtension">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    <xsl:variable name="extension">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($input, '.')"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($extension, '.')">
        <xsl:variable name="afterextension">
          <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetFileNameWithoutExtension">
            <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$extension"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($input, '.'), $afterextension)"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="contains($input, '.')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($input, '.')"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$input"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

XML Sample
    <xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
<s:Schema id='RowsetSchema'>
<s:ElementType name='row' content='eltOnly' rs:CommandTimeout='30'>
  <s:AttributeType name='ows_Attachments' rs:name='Attachments' rs:number='1'>
     <s:datatype dt:type='boolean' dt:maxLength='1' />
  </s:AttributeType>
  <s:AttributeType name='ows_LinkTitle' rs:name='Title' rs:number='2'>
     <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='512' />
  </s:AttributeType>
  <s:AttributeType name='ows_Creation_x0020_Date_x0020_Overri' rs:name='Creation Date Override' rs:number='3'>
     <s:datatype dt:type='datetime' dt:maxLength='8' />
  </s:AttributeType>
  <s:AttributeType name='ows_News_x0020_Source' rs:name='News Source' rs:number='4'>
     <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='512' />
  </s:AttributeType>
  <s:AttributeType name='ows_Original_x0020_Author' rs:name='Original Author' rs:number='5'>
     <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='512' />
  </s:AttributeType>
  <s:AttributeType name='ows_Original_x0020_Publishing_x0020_' rs:name='Original Publishing Date' rs:number='6'>
     <s:datatype dt:type='datetime' dt:maxLength='8' />
  </s:AttributeType>
  <s:AttributeType name='ows_Month_x0020_ID' rs:name='Month ID' rs:number='7'>
     <s:datatype dt:type='variant' dt:lookup='true' dt:maxLength='8009' />
  </s:AttributeType>
  <s:AttributeType name='ows_ISODate' rs:name='ISODate' rs:number='8'>
     <s:datatype dt:type='variant' dt:lookup='true' dt:maxLength='8009' />
  </s:AttributeType>
  <s:AttributeType name='ows_Category' rs:name='Category' rs:number='9'>
     <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='512' />
  </s:AttributeType>
  <s:AttributeType name='ows_Group_x0020_Order' rs:name='Group Order' rs:number='10'>
     <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:lookup='true' dt:maxLength='512' />
  </s:AttributeType>
  <s:AttributeType name='ows_Group_x0020_Order_x003a_HomePage' rs:name='Group Order:HomePage Order' rs:number='11'>
     <s:datatype dt:type='float' dt:lookup='true' dt:maxLength='8' />
  </s:AttributeType>
</s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
<z:row ows_Attachments='0' ows_LinkTitle='Math, science basics get a boost with summer camp classes at CSU Stanislaus' ows_Creation_x0020_Date_x0020_Overri='2014-08-15 00:00:00' ows_News_x0020_Source='The Modesto Bee' ows_Original_x0020_Author='NAN AUSTIN' ows_Original_x0020_Publishing_x0020_='2014-06-27 00:00:00' ows_Month_x0020_ID='float;#8.00000000000000' ows_ISODate='string;#201408' ows_Category='Editorials and Commentary' ows_Group_x0020_Order='2;#Editorials and Commentary' ows_Group_x0020_Order_x003a_HomePage='2;#2.00000000000000' />
<z:row ows_Attachments='0' ows_LinkTitle='Fresno State readies for tablet experiment' ows_Creation_x0020_Date_x0020_Overri='2014-08-15 00:00:00' ows_News_x0020_Source='The Fresno Bee' ows_Original_x0020_Author='Hannah Furfao' ows_Original_x0020_Publishing_x0020_='2014-06-27 00:00:00' ows_Month_x0020_ID='float;#8.00000000000000' ows_ISODate='string;#201408' ows_Category='Blogs and Columns' ows_Group_x0020_Order='6;#Blogs and Columns' ows_Group_x0020_Order_x003a_HomePage='6;#6.00000000000000' />
<z:row ows_Attachments='0' ows_LinkTitle='Archived Story' ows_Creation_x0020_Date_x0020_Overri='2014-08-15 00:00:00' ows_News_x0020_Source='Daily Planet' ows_Original_x0020_Author='Clark Kent' ows_Original_x0020_Publishing_x0020_='2014-07-01 00:00:00' ows_Month_x0020_ID='float;#8.00000000000000' ows_ISODate='string;#201408' ows_Category='California News' ows_Group_x0020_Order='4;#California News' ows_Group_x0020_Order_x003a_HomePage='4;#4.00000000000000' />
<z:row ows_Attachments='0' ows_LinkTitle='Test 814' ows_Creation_x0020_Date_x0020_Overri='2014-08-15 00:00:00' ows_News_x0020_Source='Test 814' ows_Original_x0020_Author='Tester' ows_Original_x0020_Publishing_x0020_='2014-08-14 00:00:00' ows_Month_x0020_ID='float;#8.00000000000000' ows_ISODate='string;#201408' ows_Category='CSU Campus News' ows_Group_x0020_Order='1;#CSU Campus News' ows_Group_x0020_Order_x003a_HomePage='1;#1.00000000000000' />
<z:row ows_Attachments='0' ows_LinkTitle='Nat News' ows_Creation_x0020_Date_x0020_Overri='2014-08-15 00:00:00' ows_News_x0020_Source='Internet' ows_Original_x0020_Author='George Castanza' ows_Original_x0020_Publishing_x0020_='2014-06-09 00:00:00' ows_Month_x0020_ID='float;#8.00000000000000' ows_ISODate='string;#201408' ows_Category='National News' ows_Group_x0020_Order='5;#National News' ows_Group_x0020_Order_x003a_HomePage='5;#5.00000000000000' />
<z:row ows_Attachments='0' ows_LinkTitle='Fake News' ows_Creation_x0020_Date_x0020_Overri='2014-08-15 00:00:00' ows_News_x0020_Source='Test' ows_Original_x0020_Author='Testr' ows_Original_x0020_Publishing_x0020_='2014-05-09 00:00:00' ows_Month_x0020_ID='float;#8.00000000000000' ows_ISODate='string;#201408' ows_Category='Editorials and Commentary' ows_Group_x0020_Order='2;#Editorials and Commentary' ows_Group_x0020_Order_x003a_HomePage='2;#2.00000000000000' />
<z:row ows_Attachments='0' ows_LinkTitle='Fake News 2' ows_Creation_x0020_Date_x0020_Overri='2014-08-15 00:00:00' ows_News_x0020_Source='Test 814' ows_Original_x0020_Author='George Castanza' ows_Original_x0020_Publishing_x0020_='2014-01-14 00:00:00' ows_Month_x0020_ID='float;#8.00000000000000' ows_ISODate='string;#201408' ows_Category='Blogs and Columns' ows_Group_x0020_Order='6;#Blogs and Columns' ows_Group_x0020_Order_x003a_HomePage='6;#6.00000000000000' />
<z:row ows_Attachments='0' ows_LinkTitle='December' ows_Creation_x0020_Date_x0020_Overri='2014-08-15 00:00:00' ows_News_x0020_Source='December' ows_Original_x0020_Author='December' ows_Original_x0020_Publishing_x0020_='2014-08-19 00:00:00' ows_Month_x0020_ID='float;#8.00000000000000' ows_ISODate='string;#201408' ows_Category='Editorials and Commentary' ows_Group_x0020_Order='2;#Editorials and Commentary' ows_Group_x0020_Order_x003a_HomePage='2;#2.00000000000000' />
<z:row ows_Attachments='0' ows_LinkTitle='sAS' ows_Creation_x0020_Date_x0020_Overri='2014-08-15 00:00:00' ows_News_x0020_Source='TEST' ows_Original_x0020_Author='TEST' ows_Original_x0020_Publishing_x0020_='2014-08-11 00:00:00' ows_Month_x0020_ID='float;#8.00000000000000' ows_ISODate='string;#201408' ows_Category='National News' ows_Group_x0020_Order='5;#National News'   ows_Group_x0020_Order_x003a_HomePage='5;#5.00000000000000' />
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

Lookup List Columns (List is called Category Order)

Title - Single line of text
HomePage Order - Number
Created By - Person or Group
Modified By - Person or Group

I assumed for GroupType (Using HomePage Order) the GroupType would still be lookup?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you for looking.

Comment: I'd like to help, but I'm afraid there isn't enough information in your question to help you. The XSLT you show is only about two templates, not a full (minimal!) XSLT that illustrates your problem. Also, without the input XML and a clear idea of your output XML (example would be nice) I'm afraid we can't get far.

Comment: Also,t he example is not valid XSLT. For instance, the expression `@*      name(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@Groupx0020Order)=$Group]` is not legal XPath, you should receive an error for it.

Comment: I have added the rest of the main xsl, and header xsl. I also provided the xml for the list. Long story short, when I group items by the Group Order ID, I need to display the Category (Group Order Title Field on Category List). Thank you for your help. Let me know if you need any additional information.